# Ingres DB JDBC connection closed and does not recover

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, jdbc, ingres

We have a Hibernate/JDBC connection within our Grails application to a ingress db:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = 'validate'
    url = "jdbc:ingres://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:II7/test"
    driverClassName = "com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver"
    username = "ingres"
    password = "ingres"
    jmxEnabled = true
    initialSize = 5
    maxActive = 50
    minIdle = 5
    maxIdle = 25
    maxWait = 10000
    maxAge = 10 * 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
    validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
    validationQueryTimeout = 3
    validationInterval = 15000
    testOnBorrow = true
    testWhileIdle = true
    testOnReturn = true
    jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
    defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
}
```

Our database crashed and we had to restart it. Since then we get severall errors and though we can access the ingres db from SQL tool Grails app does not recover.

**Any ideas of what we can do? Something like reconnect on failure?**

Following states our log when we access a page or any other action which touches the db via hibernate:

```
[13 Jan 2016 13:28:31,492] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [ERROR] - Connection failed.
[13 Jan 2016 13:28:31,492] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [ERROR] - Read timed out
[13 Jan 2016 13:28:31,648] org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver [ERROR] - SQLTransactionRollbackException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/myDomain/show/21
Connection failed.. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Connection failed.
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.findWhere(GormStaticApi.groovy:622)
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController.show(myDomainController.groovy:47)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
[13 Jan 2016 13:28:32,961] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [ERROR] - Connection closed.

[13 Jan 2016 13:28:33,008] org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver [ERROR] - SQLNonTransientConnectionException occurred when processing request: [PUT] /test/myDomain/update/21
Connection closed.. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection closed.
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController.withmyDomain(myDomainController.groovy:82)
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController$_closure2.doCall(myDomainController.groovy:34)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
[13 Jan 2016 13:28:37,727] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [ERROR] - Connection closed.

[13 Jan 2016 13:28:37,727] org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver [ERROR] - SQLNonTransientConnectionException occurred when processing request: [PUT] /test/myDomain/update/21
Connection closed.. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection closed.
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController.withmyDomain(myDomainController.groovy:82)
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController$_closure2.doCall(myDomainController.groovy:34)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
[13 Jan 2016 13:28:46,930] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [ERROR] - Connection closed.

[13 Jan 2016 13:28:46,961] org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver [ERROR] - SQLNonTransientConnectionException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/
Connection closed.. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection closed.
    at grails.orm.PagedResultList.<init>(PagedResultList.java:43)
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.createPagedResultList(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:163)
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController$_closure1.doCall(myDomainController.groovy:19)
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController.index(myDomainController.groovy:14)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
[13 Jan 2016 13:28:51,883] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [ERROR] - Connection closed.

[13 Jan 2016 13:28:51,883] org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver [ERROR] - SQLNonTransientConnectionException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/;jsessionid=
Connection closed.. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection closed.
    at grails.orm.PagedResultList.<init>(PagedResultList.java:43)
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.createPagedResultList(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:163)
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController$_closure1.doCall(myDomainController.groovy:19)
    at net.some.test.lvb.myDomainController.index(myDomainController.groovy:14)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)

[13 Jan 2016 13:29:01,008] grails.app.services.net.some.test.lvb.TaskExecuterService [DEBUG] - Started processing tasks.
[13 Jan 2016 13:29:01,008] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [ERROR] - Connection closed.
[13 Jan 2016 13:29:01,008] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate [ERROR] - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Hibernate operation: could not prepare statement; SQL [select this_.id as id1_1_0_, this_.version as version2_1_0_, this_.basis as basis3_1_0_, this_.changeDate as changeDa4_1_0_, this_.deleted as deleted5_1_0_, this_.name as name6_1_0_, this_.notice as notice7_1_0_, this_.referenceDate as referenc8_1_0_, this_.selector as selector9_1_0_, this_.specialIdentification as special10_1_0_, this_.turnus as turnus11_1_0_ from FA_myDomain this_]; Connection closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection closed.
    at net.some.test.lvb.TaskExecuterService.processmyDomain(TaskExecuterService.groovy:66)
    at net.some.test.lvb.TaskExecuterService.$tt__processTasks(TaskExecuterService.groovy:40)
    at net.some.test.lvb.TaskExecuterJob.execute(TaskExecuterJob.groovy:10)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection closed.
    ... 6 more
[13 Jan 2016 13:29:01,024] org.quartz.core.JobRunShell [INFO] - Job GRAILS_JOBS.net.some.test.lvb.TaskExecuterJob threw a JobExecutionException: 
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed [See nested exception: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed]
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    at net.some.test.lvb.TaskExecuterJob.execute(TaskExecuterJob.groovy:10)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid transaction state for requested operation.
    ... 4 more
[13 Jan 2016 13:29:01,024] grails.plugins.quartz.listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener [ERROR] - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed [See nested exception: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed]
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    at net.some.test.lvb.TaskExecuterJob.execute(TaskExecuterJob.groovy:10)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid transaction state for requested operation.
    ... 4 more
```